# como hacer un contador de arrays aleatorios en C

Tags: c, array, contador

buenas, el programa consiste en realizar una serie de tiradas N de un dado y contar el numero de veces que sale un numero pedido por pantalla. Este es el codigo que he hecho pero algo falla en el contador :(   Gracias de antemano.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N 500
#define M 6

void obtenerRonda( int A[] ) {    
  int array[N];
  int i;
  srand( time( NULL ) );

  for( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
    array[i] = 1 + ( rand( ) % M );
    printf( "-%d-", array[i] );
  } 
}

int repeticion( int V[] ) {
  int i ;
  int t = 0;
  int numero;

  printf( "\nQue numero quieres saber cuantas veces se ha repetido" );
  scanf( "%d", &numero );

  for( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
    if( V[i] == numero ) {
      t++;
    }
  }

  printf( "el numero %d se repite %d veces ", numero, t );
}

int main( void ){
  int A[N];

  obtenerRonda( A );
  repeticion( A );
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Debes decirnos que es lo que falla.. no podemos inferir por el codigo que es lo que falla, sin saber que estamos buscando...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que tienes en el programa es que el arreglo `int A[N]` no ha sido inicializado correctamente. Sólo estas inicializando el arreglo local `int array[N]` en la función `void obtenerRonda( int A[] )` cuando al parecer deberías de utilizar `A[]`.

Esta es la implementación adecuada:

```
void obtenerRonda( int A[] ) {    
  int i;
  srand( time( NULL ) );

  for( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
      A[i] = 1 + ( rand( ) % M );
      printf( "-%d-", A[i] );
   } 
}
```

Notarás que eliminé la variable `int array[N]`. Como comentario, el arreglo array[] se crerá en la pila de la función y se "destruirá" una vez saliendo de la función. En realidad en `int A[]` al no haber sido inicializado tenías valores basura.

El código completo lo puedes encontrar [aquí](https://www.onlinegdb.com/S1IeUS0AZ)

Comment: ¿ Algo que añadir sobre la función `int repeticion( )` que no devuelve nada ?

Comment: @Trauma Cierto. No consideré adecuado mencionarlo debido que al parecer no considera que la función retorne un valor. @Cornetto, como sugiere Trauma, deberás considerar cambiar el valor de retorno de `repeticion` a `void`. Hará tu código mas claro.